# Salesforce Marketing Cloud_monitoring API usage

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Is there any approach to monitor API usage in Salesforce Marketing Cloud? 
Please give my insight and share your knowledge,

Best,
Colin

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to measure it yourself, other than keeping count and logging your own activities manually by some automation.

Currently the only way to do it is via Marketing Cloud Support by raising a new case or asking from your Account Executive.

This has been requested [7 months ago](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TuXdQAK) in the Idea portal, doubtful that this will be implemented anytime soon.